# How to make a moving background in flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation

I have come across this particular animation for onboarding.
https://dribbble.com/shots/15258844-Airbus-Tripset-iOS-app
and am planning to do something similar. Any ideas on how to start?

Comment: What research into Flutter animations have you done already?

Comment: I note that a lot (if not most?) of the cool examples on Dribbble are made with prototyping tools (Adobe XD, etc) or even general-purpose animation software (AE, Blender, etc), so it's oftentimes you'll see things on there that still aren't feasible in production software.

Comment: i will suggest to use https://rive.app/  to make this type of complex animations

Comment: @Dai, I am new to flutter and am clueless on how to go doing such kind of animation.

Comment: I will update the comment in case I am able to arrive at a solution

Answer (score 1):

Hi Panduranga Rao Sadhu,

I would like to recommend you the AnimatedAlign class for images on onboarding pages.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedAlign-class.html

Besides, i would like to suggest SlideTransition class for the transition between onboarding pages.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SlideTransition-class.html

If you want something else, you can find lot of animations in flutter.
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/animation